# How can I replay a memory with Zelda?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I recently unlocked my first "memory" with Zelda. I would like to revisit it and pay attention to the conversation that happened in it. How do I re-play a restored memory with Zelda?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to go to your Adventure Log (the screen left of your inventory) and scroll over to the Memories page.  There you'll be able to revisit any restored memories.

[image: Memories in the Adventure Log]

Answer (score 2):

You can view recalled memories from the Adventure Log. The fourth option, on the right of Main Quest, Shrine Quests and Side Quests, is the Memories page. All memories, locked and unlocked, are listed, and you can watch memories you have recalled.

You can see which place has triggered a memory from the Album in the Sheikah Slate from the film icon in the bottom right corner of the picture, but it's impossible to watch memories from there.